# Open Windows 'Run' dialog using a command and Remember position on screen?

Tags: windows, command-line, operating-systems, user-interface, run-dialog

There's a good command here to open Windows 'Run' dialog:
[Open Run... dialog from command](https://superuser.com/questions/533485/open-run-dialog-from-command/807175#807175)

I wish a little bit more customised, that is

- how to set the position of the Run dialog, or
- how to make the Run dialog remember its last position on screen

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try these fixes

Fix #1:
Right-click on the Taskbar and choose Cascade. That should put the window on the screen. Stretch the window out to the desired size and close it. It should open that size next time.

Fix #2:
Download and install [ShellFolderFix](http://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/shellfolderfix.html)